# My profile appears in the Google search result when I search my old profile name

Tags: support, asking-questions, profile-page

Despite changing my *Display name* and also my *Full name* in my profile and selecting the option *Save and copy changes to all public communities*, when I search my old display name in google, my Stack Exchange profile (all communities) appear in the search result. How is this even possible?

I have changed my full name and also my display name.

Comment: How? Scrapping and caching. That's what Google does

Comment: My display name was something else (it was my first name and last name). I have changed it for almost 2 weeks and now to Pani. When I search my full name which was my profile previous display name , i see my profile !! Now it does not contain my full name !! how it shows up in the result? How can I prevent this from happening?? is there a way?

Comment: should I contact google team?

Comment: You can contact google, but I wouldn't expect much. SO definitely isn't able to help you here.

Comment: Well you could certainly try asking Google, there's not much SO can do on their end except maybe triggering a recrawl but even that can take weeks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you need to ask Google to [remove outdated content](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6349986). In principle, since your profile page has changed, Google Search should get updated eventually, but if I understand correctly filling out the form as described at the link above should speed up the process.

Also remember that Google is not the only search engine - [here's a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_search_engines). You may want to get search results removed from some of those as well.

Comment: There also insane number of clones of SO which all scrape as much content as possible and try to get top spots in search engines... and unlikely to entertain/respect any privacy requests.